# how can I generate a website overview in a video

Tags: html, video

I have a project with an online client so to assure that he won't take my website I want a software or any technology that may help me to present my website in a video. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to SO, we answer more code related questions here, that is why your qustion is downvoted. For your question look for screen to video softwares like camstudio. You can make a video of your screen while navigating on the site.

Comment: Not a programmer question on-off topic should be avoided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you're looking for is screen recorder software, there are plenty of these out there.

Here are some useful ones: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/win-screen-recording-softwares/

Answer (score 0):

Try recording it with fraps or something

Comment: Fraps cannot be used to complete this task as fraps is only used for recording gameplay.

Comment: There are tricks to record browsers with it, did it many times but he could also use others. This was just an example